# Drupal - How can I pass data to contextual filter of view through QuickTab module?

Tags: drupal

I want to pass arguments to the contextual filter of a view through quicktab module.

For this, I have created a view as a block, made the Use Ajax=Yes, and added the taxonomy term as contextual filter. See scree below:

[image]

Now I have added quicktab module and created the tabs as show in the below screen shot.

[image]

I'm passing the value as arguments through the quicktab module however, the accordion shows nothing. See screen below:

[image]

PS - The arguments are 1, 2 etc as these are the term IDs of taxonomy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your views argument as " Display all results for the specified field" and then in quick tab pass your term id corresponding.

Thanks

Comment: I did the required change in the view as you suggested. Now clicking on any tab, all the contents are showing.

Comment: Actually I see that there is no way to send arguments (term ids) as I don't want page refresh.

Comment: Its working Sunil. I made the changes the renderer as qtabs from accordion and cleaned the cache then.